# Convert currency to decimal number JavaScript

Tags: javascript, regex

How can I convert currency string like this `$123,456,78.3` to number like this `12345678.3`
I tried to do using this pattern

```
let str = "$123,456,78.3";
let newStr = str.replace(/\D/g, '');
```

but it replaces `.`  too.

Comment: Just pasting your subject in web search returns lots of results that should have enabled you to find solutions

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var str = "$123,456,78.3";
var newStr = Number(str.replace(/[^0-9.-]+/g,""));
```

Answer (score 2):

Use a lowercase `d`, and put it into a negated character group along with the `.`.

```js
let str = "$123,456,78.3";
let newStr = str.replace(/[^\d.]/g, '');

console.log(newStr)
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use a negative character group:

```js
"$123,456,78.3".replace(/[^\d.]/g, "")
```