# How convert string value in Javascript for decimal number

Tags: javascript, type-conversion, helper

How to convert R$ 800,000.00 in string type to 800000 decimal type using JavaScript?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Convert currency to decimal number JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63321294/convert-currency-to-decimal-number-javascript) then pass the result to `Number`

Answer (score 0):

Why don’t you just use
`currenyValueInt = parseInt(currencyValueString.split(" ")[1])`

Answer (score 0):

You sanitize the string by replacing everything but digits and the decimal separator and then cast it to a Number, either with `Number()` or by simply adding a `+` in front of the expression:

```js
let str = +"R$ 800,000.00".replace(/[^\d.]/g, '');

console.log(str, typeof str)
```